# How can I tell if I have military grade ammo loaded?

Tags: metro-2033

When playing Metro 2033 it is possible to load military grade bullets into your weapon that do more damage, but the bullets are also used as currency so they are to be used wisely. However, the somewhat annoying way the game handles loading ammo is that it loads military grade ammo if you hold down the reload button. It seems to be very sensitive and I sometimes end up loading military ammo when I wanted to load normal ammo - and waste valuable ammo as a result. How can I tell if I have accidentally loaded the wrong ammo type?

Comment: Have you tried to hold tab(Y on xbox controller)? Or are you playing in ranger mode?

Comment: @Nils I'm on PC, playing in ranger mode

Comment: bad news =[ , in the ranger mode you will have to look/listen to the ammunition you are using. I found some workaround but I don't know if it works on the original version, updated my answer with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Military Grade Ammo is the game currency and it have a gold and shinny aspect, you can see it when reloading. The other ammo have and old and dirty aspect.

> Dirty rounds can be distinguished from military-grade rounds by the way they're stored: Dirty rounds go in cloth pouches, AK-style box magazines and, rarely, VSV mags; MGR are kept either as a single bullet, in five round stripper clips or in the rectangular 30-round clips for the Bastard. Developers have also stated military-grade rounds have a polished, glossy look to them, while dirty rounds are, for lack of a better word - dirty.
> Source: http://metrovideogame.wikia.com/wiki/MGR

In normal mode(non-ranger modes) you can hold `TAB`(keyboard), `Y` (xbox controller) to show it.

Only the Bastard shows the clip, so I ranger mode you will have to pay attention while reloading be it when pressing the key or when reaching the magazine.

At 0:34 he changes from dirty to MGR using the Bastard

**Workaround for Metro 2033 Redux** (the Y and TAB seens to work on Redux ranger mode)

> "bring up your lighter and clipboard. Then right click to see your ammo.
>
> I don't think you can see how many rounds are in your clip. The ammo count that you see in ranger only counts unloaded ammo and doesn't count ammo already in a clip."
>
> source: http://steamcommunity.com/app/286690/discussions/0/613935403981744073/

Steam comunity guide for ammo: http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=313996974&insideModal=1